# Removing on click Listener from all buttons?

Tags: android, onclick, listener

I'm making a simple 'tic tac toe' game and so I have 9 buttons. These 9 buttons have the same
on click listener which I set in the layout "on click" property so that I don't have to create 9 buttons in code just to set the listener.

My problem is that I have to remove all the listeners
from the buttons when a game is won or tied.

Is there a way to loop through all the buttons without actually having to create 9 button variables and setting each listener to null?

My code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button b = (Button) v;
    Integer tag = Integer.parseInt((String) b.getTag());
    values[tag] = turnToPlay;
    b.setText(turnToPlay);
    b.setOnClickListener(null);
    playerTurn.setText("Player " + turnToPlay + " turn");

    if(isBoardFull()) {
        playerWon.setText("Tie Game!!");
        removeAllListeners()
    }

    if(turnToPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
        turnToPlay = "O";
    }

    else {
        turnToPlay = "X";
    }    
}
```

Comment: can you post the code you are using for your current clickListener?

Comment: @mario: You could always just use a `Boolean` class variable called `processClick` or similar. When a game is won or tied, set it to `false` and have the `onClick(...)` method ignore any clicks until it's reset to `true`.

Comment: @misterSquonk: Hmmm, didnt think of that xD thanks ahahha. It's still good to know both ways

Comment: @mario: lol - a simple boolean switch can be quite powerful sometimes. Have fun. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this function to traverse the view tree and remove all listeners:

```
public void removeListeners() {
    View topView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    traverseTree(topView);
}

private void traverseTree(View view) {

    if(view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)view;
            for(int index = 0; index < group.
                getChildCount(); index++) {
                traverseTree(group.getChildAt(index));
            }
        } 

        else if (view instanceof Button) {
            Button button = (Button)view;
            button.setOnClickListener(null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you say tic tack toe and currently using one event for all the buttons. will this not be more apt, since the user is suppose to click only once on a square.

```
View.OnClickListener onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {     
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.b1:
                //...
            break;

            case R.id.b2:

            break;              

        }           
        v.setOnClickListener(null);         
    }
};
```